# Sumar valores de filas de un matriz usando hilos en c

Tags: c, hilos

Tengo el siguiente codigo donde siendo declarada una matriz, usando hilos se deben sumar los valores de cada fila haciendo uso de un hilo para cada fila.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void *Suma(void *ptr);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int op1;
  int op2;
  int fila;
  int m[4][4] = { 1, 2, 0, 0, 1, 1, 3, 4, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3};

  pthread_t hilo1, hilo2, hilo3, hilo4;
  int it1, it2, it3, it4;

  if (argc != 3) {
    printf("invalid %s", argv[0]);
  }

  op1 = atoi(argv[1]);
  op2 = atoi(argv[2]);

  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
      printf("%d", m[i][j]);
    }
  }

  if (op1) {
    it1 = pthread_create(&hilo1, NULL, Suma, (void *)m[0]);

    it2 = pthread_create(&hilo2, NULL, Suma, (void *)m[1]);

    it3 = pthread_create(&hilo3, NULL, Suma, (void *)m[2]);

    it4 = pthread_create(&hilo4, NULL, Suma, (void *)m[3]);

    pthread_join(hilo1, NULL);
    pthread_join(hilo2, NULL);
    pthread_join(hilo3, NULL);
    pthread_join(hilo4, NULL);

    printf("%d\n", it1);
    printf("%d\n", it2);
    printf("%d\n", it3);
    printf("%d\n", it4);
    exit(0);
  }
}

void *Suma(void *ptr) {
  int fila, columna, resultado = 0;
  int *m[4][4];
  m[0][0] = (int *)ptr;
  for (fila = 0; fila < 4; fila++) {
    resultado = 0;
    for (columna = 0; columna < 4; columna++) {
      resultado += *m[fila][columna];
      printf("%d", resultado);
    }
  }
  return NULL;
}
```

El programa compila pero al momento de ejecutarlos me el error "Segmentation fault (core dumped)".

Se que probablemente haya un error con el codigo y la verdad estoy algo perdido con este tema de hilos. A veces me daba errores con la matriz declarada debido al tema de punteros por lo que la deje simplemente como un int. Agradezco si pueden ayudarme.

Comment: Qué eliges con `op1 = atoi(argv[1]);`?

Comment: @Mateo Es que segun la opción del usuario al ejecutar, la opción 1 suma los valores de las filas y la opción 2 imprime el maximo de cada fila, cosa que aún no he hecho.

Comment: ¿Y qué parámetro le das al programa?

Comment: @Mateo Al programa? O a la función? Porque si es a la función según yo le doy de parámetro la matriz para procesar las filas.

Comment: Al programa. Por favor pon la información en la pregunta. Es importante y así mantenemos la zona de comentarios más limpia.

Comment: Has etiquetado la pregunta como [tag:c++] pero el código es todo [tag:c], C++ y C son lenguajes distintos y la solución será distinta en cada lenguaje. ¿De qué lenguaje quieres formular la pregunta?

Comment: No faltan las llaves intermedias? ```
int m[4][4] = { 1, 2, 0, 0, 1, 1, 3, 4, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3};
```

Comment: Si lo fuera el compilador daría error. Sin embargo el problema sucede a la hora de ejecutar el programa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La causa del error fue la forma en que utilizaste el puntero y sobre el hecho de que al ejecutarlo, da error es que en la compilación solo se verifica la sintaxis pero no la lógica, y el programa se compila pero no se ejecuta.

Un ejemplo de compilación que no da error pero que da error en la ejecución sería:

```
 int x = 10;
 int y = 0;

 int res = x / y;
    
 printf("El resultado =  %d", res);
```

**(**  *La lógica es que cualquier número dividido por cero resultará en un error matemático* **)**

En relación al puntero, lo que se hizo fue asignar un nuevo puntero a la matriz y no se pasó a la función `pthread_create()`. Esto hizo que la hebra no tuviera acceso a la matriz original.

Lo que puedes hacer es pasar el puntero a la matriz original a pthread_create().

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
 

int matrix[4][4] = {
    {1, 2, 0, 0},
    {1, 1, 3, 4},
    {2, 1, 1, 0},
    {0, 0, 0, 3}
};

void *Suma(void *ptr) {
    int fila, columna, resultado = 0;
    int *m = (int *)ptr;
    
    for (fila = 0; fila < 4; fila++) {
        resultado = 0;
        for (columna = 0; columna < 4; columna++) {
            resultado += *(m + fila * 4 + columna);
        }
        printf(%d\n", resultado);
    }
    
    return NULL;
}

int main() {
        pthread_t hilo1, hilo2, hilo3, hilo4;

        int *m1 = malloc(sizeof(int) * 4 * 4);
        int *m2 = malloc(sizeof(int) * 4 * 4);
        int *m3 = malloc(sizeof(int) * 4 * 4);
        int *m4 = malloc(sizeof(int) * 4 * 4);

        /*Realiza una copia de la matriz original
           para cada matriz asignada*/

        memcpy(m1, matrix, sizeof(int) * 4 * 4);
        memcpy(m2, matrix, sizeof(int) * 4 * 4);
        memcpy(m3, matrix, sizeof(int) * 4 * 4);
        memcpy(m4, matrix, sizeof(int) * 4 * 4);

        pthread_create(&hilo1, NULL, Suma, (void *)m1);
        pthread_create(&hilo2, NULL, Suma, (void *)m2);
        pthread_create(&hilo3, NULL, Suma, (void *)m3);
        pthread_create(&hilo4, NULL, Suma, (void *)m4);

        pthread_join(hilo1, NULL);
        pthread_join(hilo2, NULL);
        pthread_join(hilo3, NULL);
        pthread_join(hilo4, NULL);

        free(m1);
        free(m2);
        free(m3);
        free(m4);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Resultado:

```
 3
 9
 4
 3
 3
 9
 4
 3
 3
 9
 4
 3
 3
 9
 4
 3
```

Los resultados repetidos ocurren porque se están creando cuatro hilos que ejecutan la función `Suma`. *Otra posibilidad es dividir la matriz entre los hilos, de manera que cada hilo procese una parte de la matriz.*

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int matrix[4][4] = {
    {1, 2, 0, 0},
    {1, 1, 3, 4},
    {2, 1, 1, 0},
    {0, 0, 0, 3}
};

void *Suma(void *ptr) {
    int inicio = *((int *)ptr);
    int fin = inicio + 4 / 4;
    int resultado = 0;

    for (int fila = inicio; fila < fin; fila++) {
        for (int columna = 0; columna < 4; columna++) {
            resultado += matrix[fila][columna];
        }
    }

    printf("%d\n", resultado);

    return NULL;
}

int main() {
        
        pthread_t hilo1, hilo2, hilo3, hilo4;
      
        int filas[4] = {0, 1, 2, 3};
        pthread_create(&hilo1, NULL, Suma, &filas[0]);
        pthread_create(&hilo2, NULL, Suma, &filas[1]);
        pthread_create(&hilo3, NULL, Suma, &filas[2]);
        pthread_create(&hilo4, NULL, Suma, &filas[3]);

        pthread_join(hilo1, NULL);
        pthread_join(hilo2, NULL);
        pthread_join(hilo3, NULL);
        pthread_join(hilo4, NULL);
    

    return 0;
}
```

resultado

```
9
4
3
3
```